# Renaming substring in unix filenames

Tags: regex, unix, rename

I have a load of files of the format:

```
output_t00010000-0470090205_p000000.xdr
output_t00010000-0470090205_p000001.xdr
```

etc.

What I really want is to find all files which match *t00010000*, and for each file that matches that, rename t00010000-0470090205 to t00000000-0000000000.

So I did something like this:

```
find . -depth -name *t00010000* | xargs rename t00010000-0470090205 t00000000-0000000000
```

This works fine when I know the second half of the substring e.g. 0470090205, but this substring is randomly generated depending on the simulation I run and I don't know it in advance. So what I REALLY want is something like:

```
find . -depth -name *t00010000* | xargs rename t00010000-?????????? t00000000-0000000000
```

but rename doesn't let me use the ? character matching symbol. I am really struggling how to figure this out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to `rename` are:

```
rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]
```

The *perlexpr* should be a Perl expression that transforms the original name into the new name. In your case it would be:

```
rename 's/t\d+-\d+/t00000000-0000000000/'
```

So:

```
find . -depth -name *t00010000* | xargs rename 's/t\d+-\d+/t00000000-0000000000/'
```

A nice way to test `rename` is with the `-n` option, which will show you what each file would be renamed to without doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the -n tip, I will definitely use that in future.